# React native get default style props?

Tags: react-native

How can I get the default style props from inside my React Native app or with a debugging tool? I tried with React `Devtools`, but they only show the props that I set, not the default ones. But I am interested in the default values. How can I watch them? I do not want to depend on the documentation and want to really check it in my running app. I am using functional components.

Comment: Are you looking to get the default style of components provided by React Native or your custom components? Can you elaborate some more with an example?

Comment: @fayeed Of components provided by React Native e.g. `<Text>`. For example how do I get the default flex properties for text, the default text font size etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the source of `react-native`. the default props have seemed to be `undefined` under most circumstances. For example, see the Text export from the react-native:-

```
const Text = (
  props: TextProps,
  forwardedRef: ?React.Ref<'RCTText' | 'RCTVirtualText'>,
) => {
  return <TouchableText {...props} forwardedRef={forwardedRef} />;
};
const TextToExport = React.forwardRef(Text);
TextToExport.displayName = 'Text';

// TODO: Deprecate this.
/* $FlowFixMe(>=0.89.0 site=react_native_fb) This comment suppresses an error
 * found when Flow v0.89 was deployed. To see the error, delete this comment
 * and run Flow. */
TextToExport.propTypes = DeprecatedTextPropTypes;

module.exports = ((TextToExport: $FlowFixMe): Class<
  NativeComponent<TextProps>,
>);
```

So Here `TouchableText` is the real component with some default props. You will be able to check the TouchableText's props in the `react-native debugger`.

As a conclusion, if we cannot see the default props of a component, is just because it doesn't have any. All the styles and other properties we feel in components are the default properties those components have on the native side.
So I don't think there exists a way to get what you are trying to get, because they don't actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can get and modify default props by importing that component.
For example, I used the following code to modify FlatList behavior globally including node modules that I am using:

```
if (FlatList.defaultProps == null) {
  FlatList.defaultProps = {}
}
FlatList.defaultProps.initialNumToRender = 10
FlatList.defaultProps.maxToRenderPerBatch = 10
FlatList.defaultProps.scrollEventThrottle = 15
FlatList.defaultProps.bounces = false
```

I believe that you can use console.warn or console.log inside render method of a scene to see its content.

Inside render block place following code:

```
render(){
   console.warn(FlatList.defaultProps)
   return (
     <View>
     ...
     </View>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example with sample outputs, e.g. for font size and flex?

Comment: Thank you! I went with the other answer though, as it's closer to what I wanted to know. E.g. on your output, things like flex are missing - because they are not defined like the other answer explains.